# PHP Socket Write End of Message

Tags: php, sockets

I have a weird client communicating to my PHP server which socket_write a response:

```
    $write_result = socket_write($msgsock, $talkback, strlen($talkback));
    echo "Length Wrote: " .  $write_result . "\n";
```

With this code, length-wrote is correct (equal to length of $talkback), but the client is hang with status "Receiving" forever. So I added:

```
    $write_result = socket_write($msgsock, $talkback, strlen($talkback));
    echo "Length Wrote: " .  $write_result . "\n";
    socket_close($msgsock);
```

But now the client returns the error that TCP connection was shutoff unexpectedly. I'm wondering what could be the cause (Do not have access to client source code).

I've tried to end $talkback with \n\0 or \r\n but do not help.

Comment: Without the details of the protocol running on top of the socket stream its impossible to advise how to implement the communications. Voting to clise.